# Jersey REST API returning empty objects

Tags: java, jersey

I've the following course object.

```
public class Course {
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private Person person;

    public Course(){

    }
    public Course(int id, String name, Person person){
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.person = person;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }


    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }


    public Person getPerson() {
        return person;
    }
}
```

I've created the following Service class with one method.

```
public class DataService {

    public ArrayList<Course> getAllCourses(){

        ArrayList<Course> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(new Course(101, "Introduction to Java", new Person(201, "Asish", "Goswami")));
        list.add(new Course(102, "Intermediate Java", new Person(202, "Amiyo", "Bagchi")));
        list.add(new Course(103, "Advanced Java", new Person(203, "Atul", "Prasad")));
        return list;
    }
}
```

And I'm calling it using a REST service.

```
@Path("/courses")
public class CourseService {


    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public ArrayList<Course> getAllCourses(){

    DataService service = new DataService();
    return service.getAllCourses()
    }
}
```

This returns the following output,

```
[{},{},{}]
```

I've no clue what's going wrong. Any help highly appreciated.

Comment: Try adding `@XmlRootElement` on the `Course` class

Comment: Getting same issue with both @XmlRootElement and Initparam....Still waiting for proper solution..

Answer (score 0):

You will need to set `POJOMappingFeature` to true in order for Jearsey to support `serialization` of POJO into Json. It can be done by setting `init param` in deployment descriptor as shown below:

```
<init-param>
    <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</init-param>
```

[Here](http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/json-example-with-jersey-jackson/) is the full example.

Comment: This doesn't work, I tried this along with the new standard which is MOXY and still the same thing.